# Assign sql query result to compare using datediff function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use the result of query:

`Select  max(STR_TO_DATE(Replace(shipmentdate,",",""),'%d %M %Y')) as datenew     from prc.tbsrparts t where substring(partsn,17,11) = "20065100033" ;`

to compare with the `datediff` function.
I can't find a proper way to do this. Can anyone guide me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your query as `sub-select` find the `datediff` in outer query. Try this.

```
SELECT Datediff(anotherdate1, datenew)
FROM   (SELECT Max(Str_to_date(Replace(shipmentdate, ",", ""), '%d %M %Y')) AS datenew
        FROM   prc.tbsrparts t
        WHERE  Substring(partsn, 17, 11) = "20065100033") a
```

Comment: @MohamadArafat - It is just a **alias name** to `sub-select` which can be used to `refer` sub-select columns